# WebClient force Timeout

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, webclient

```
    public class MyWebClient : WebClient {

        private int timeout;
        public int Timeout
        {
            get
            {
                return timeout;
            }
            set
            {
                timeout = value;
            }
        }

        public MyWebClient()
        {
            this.timeout = 5000;
        }

        public MyWebClient(int timeout)
        {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var result = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            result.Timeout = this.timeout;
            return result;
        } 
}
```

I am trying to force timeout to 5000 milliseconds, but it is not working the download does not stop or exit after 5000 milsecs.

It can be done by Task timeout, but i don't want to use Task here.

any alternative way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

Can you give any more information? What are you trying to download from, and are you certain it's not working?

I've tried your code and it seems to work fine; I get a System.Net.WebException "The operation has timed out" - you're definitely not swallowing this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Could you put the request on a new thread, then watch that thread, if you hit your specified timeout then kill the thread thus aborting the request.